# Issues upgrading openSUSE Leap 42.1 to 42.3

Tags: opensuse, fglrx

OpenSUSE Leap 42.1 reach end of life status 2017-05-17. Today I found time and willingness to do something about it. :-)

After upgrade with `zypper dup` command and rebooting I saw a black screen. 
I managed to run SUSE in emergency mode and read `journalctl -xb output`.

I would like to paste the whole log here, but I do not know how to do it. I heard systemd logs are stored binary.

Few things I noticed in journal:

- Dependency failed for Local File System.
- Dependency failed for Local AMD External Events Deamon.
- Dependency failed for Local A service to build fglrx kernel module for new kernels.

I do have AMD Radeon 7850 and before upgrade I was using AMD proprietary driver.

After reading journal, I ran command `startx` i got black screen.

I guess the simplest solution would be switching to default drivers but I don't know how to do that.

Also I am worried about `Dependency failed for Local File System`.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Edit 1:**
As sebath suggested, I redirect journal output to file.
Logs exceeded message limit so I put it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/2EU52QfV

Comment: You could [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Redirecting_standard_input_and_standard_output) the output of `journalctl` to get a text log.

Answer (score 0):

The most common issues I have encountered are:

1. `snapper` fills the root partition to 100% -- solution:  remove snapshots.
2. proprietary video driver fails-- solution:  reinstall it.
3. `KDE` desktop issues-- solution:  delete all of the `KDE` config. files in ~
4. new kernel auto-uninstalled-- solution:  reinstall it.
5. `grub` not working-- workaround:  use USB boot and then at grub load from HDD
6. changed ~/.Xauthority and forgot:  delete customization

Unfortunately your pastebin has expired and I cannot see detail as to whether one of those scenarios applies.  If it is 1. (snapper) then your `zypper dup` may have completed with errors and write access would be denied for the root, preventing temporary log writes and such (and preventing a normal boot).